# Creating an calculator with javascript gives unexpected output

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, textarea

Heyy guys,

I am trying to create an calculator that can sum.

What I am trying to do is:

1. Search for the plus, and get the place of the plus in a number
2. Get the `product1` and `product2`
3. Sum them together to `y.value`

Now as you can see this gives not like `3 + 2 = 5`. But it gives `3 + 2 = 32`

So i see that my script doesn't see this as a number but as a string. So what do I have to do to make it working?

Thnx for all your help!

```js
function start() {
  var snelheid = 10;
  var x = document.getElementById("input");
  var y = document.getElementById("output");
  x.value = "3+2"

  function process() {
    var place_plus = x.value.indexOf("+");
    var product1 = x.value.slice(0, place_plus);
    var product2 = x.value.slice(place_plus + 1, x.value.length);
    y.value = product1 + product2;
    document.getElementById("var").innerHTML = product1 + " + " + product2 + " = " + (product1 + product2);
  }

  var animateInterval = setInterval(process, snelheid);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  start();
});
```

```html
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>

<p id="var"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the unary operator (+) to convert the string to a number:

```
var product1 = +x.value.slice(0, place_plus);
var product2 = +x.value.slice(place_plus + 1, x.value.length);
```

Comment: Thnx for you quick response!